# Is there a low cost C compiler for the 80C251 family?

Tags: c, compiler

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978189/what-is-the-best-c-compiler-for-the-8051-family but with extended support for 251.

Keil have a solution, but it's $3k. For us that investment will never be repaid.

Has anyone had success extending SDCC for such a device?  Unofficial gcc backend port?

Specifically, the core I'm trying to support is 80251 Typhoon from Dolphin Integration.

https://www.dolphin-integration.com/index.php/silicon_ip/ip_products/description/microcontrollers/Flip80251_Typhoon

Current solutions I've found:

SmartCC80251 https://www.dolphin-integration.com/index.php/newsroom/news/313 (ROM pricing TBA) (just found this, wasn't easy to find)

Keil C251 Dev Tools http://www.keil.com/c251/ (ROM USD3k)

Comment: Welcome!  *"What is the best"* questions are off-topic here, but if you edit to specify what features you need, as well as a more defined price range, the question will be on-topic and our community can possibly help you with answers.

Comment: It seems the "best" is not the issue here  if you are excluding options on price.  Specify your requirements with respect to cost, performance, optimisation, compliance, device support, debugger support, IDE, etc.  "Best" is subjective; to give an objective answer will require assesment of  _all_ possible options against your specific requirements - hardly feasible - and many vendor prohibit publishing of benchmarks in the licence small print in any case.  You are as capable of finding suitable candidates and reading the vendor brochures, and trialing evaluation licences as anyone.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I copy-pasted the title of the 8051 based question and added a '2'. To be more specific then, does anyone know of a compiler for this that is free or at least cheap (sub $300 for instance)?  I'm happy to pay for it, just not 3k.

Comment: I work as a software contractor.  My going rate is greater than $3000/ week.  Therefore, a $3000 investment in a tool  is 'peanuts'  and the overall time saved will more than repay for the investment in the tool.

Comment: @user3629249 depends on how the project is used for. What if it's just a hobby or a small project? What if the compiler isn't use further after this?